# Cumulative sum & percentage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sum

I have a table called Sales:

```
id_sale  id_ticket  total  state
-------  ---------  -----  -----
100      100        30     inactive    
101      101        30     active    
102      101        60     active    
103      102        30     active    
104      102        30     active    
105      103        10     active    
106      103        5      active
```

What I need is to get the total sum of the `total` column, sum(total) when the state is active and multiply it for x percentage (I can do that), having that I have to select all the tickets that their sum (of all the tickets summed) is `<= sum(total) * x percentage` and copy it to another table (same values)

So if I have the sum of ticket 101 = 90 and the sum of ticket 102 = 60 and the sum of ticket 103 = 15, and the sum(total)*x percentage = 160, the query will only return all the info from the tickets 101 and 102.

Reading all morning I found a code that somehow does something like what I need but using id_Sales and not id_ticket:

```
    select t1.id_sale, t1.total, SUM(t2.total) as sum
    from sales t1
    inner join sales t2 on t1.id_sale >= t2.id_sale
    where t2.state='active'
    group by t1.id_sale, t1.total
    having sum(t2.total)<=(
                           select sum(total)*.65
                           from sales
                           where state='active')
    order by t1.id_sale
```

What i espect to recieve is:

```
id_sale  id_ticket  total  state
-------  ---------  -----  ----- 
101      101        30     active    
102      101        60     active    
103      102        30     active    
104      102        30     active
```

In wich the sum of ticket 101 and ticket 102 is <= sum(total)*x

so the sum of 101 and 102 = 150 and sum(total)*x = 160 (for example)

How can I do what I need or how can I edit this code so it does what I'm looking for.

Comment: thanks for posting sample data but can you post a sample of the expected result that you need?

Comment: I wish I could +10 @bluefeet's comment. The query you tried is nice to know, but most of us would rather know what result you actually expect.

Comment: how do you pick the ticket order for the 2nd step (where you want to get up to 160 but not over) the ticket number asc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with something like this:

```
WITH grouped_and_ranked AS (
  SELECT
    id_ticket,
    ticket_total = SUM(total),
    grand_total = SUM(SUM(total)) OVER (),
    ticket_rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_ticket)
  FROM sales
  WHERE state = 'active'
  GROUP BY id_ticket
),
cumulative AS (
  SELECT
    id_ticket,
    ticket_total,
    grand_total,
    ticket_rnk,
    total_so_far = ticket_total
  FROM grouped_and_ranked
  WHERE ticket_rnk = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    r.id_ticket,
    r.ticket_total,
    r.grand_total,
    r.ticket_rnk,
    total_so_far = c.total_so_far + r.ticket_total 
  FROM grouped_and_ranked r
    INNER JOIN cumulative c ON r.ticket_rnk = c.ticket_rnk + 1
  WHERE r.ticket_total columns
)
SELECT
  s.id_sale,
  s.id_ticket,
  s.total,
  s.state
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN cumulative c ON s.id_ticket = c.id_ticket
;
```

The first [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), `grouped_and_ranked`, retrieves active sales and calculates totals by ticket as well as the grand total (using [windowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) `SUM()`). It also assigns ranking numbers to the tickets to be used later when calculating the running total.

The next CTE, `cumulative`, is a recursive CTE. It retrieves rows from the previous result set as long as the running total is no greater than the specified `@percent`'age of the grand total.

The main SELECT uses the final ticket list to get the detail rows, by joining the list back to the `sales` table.

This query can be tested [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33bec/9).

Comment: Thanks for the answere, it helped me to improve the code i was working on. Everytime i learn something new :D

Answer (score 1):

This can be done relatively easily with window functions only, without recursion.

```sql
select id_sale, id_ticket, total, state
from (
  select
    id_sale, id_ticket, total, state,

    -- Now we can calculate the cumulative percentage easily
    sum(sum_per_ticket) over (order by id_sale) / sum(sum_per_ticket) over () percentage
  from (
    select
      id_sale, id_ticket, total, state,

      -- Calculate the sum per ticket and place it only on the first row per id_ticket
      -- Fill the other rows with nulls.
      case when id_sale = 
                first_value(id_sale) over (partition by id_ticket order by id_sale) 
           then sum(total) over (partition by id_ticket) end sum_per_ticket
    from sales
    where state = 'active'
  ) t
) t
where percentage <= 0.65
order by id_sale
```

[I have blogged about calculating cumulative percentages in more detail here](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/02/14/how-to-calculate-a-cumulative-percentage-in-sql/).